# Wordpress update plugin through Dashboard/Plugins displaying error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

The update fails if I try the update through Dashboard/Plugins, but the update works if I update it thru Dashboard/Updates.
It displaying error when I try to update from Dashboard/Plugins path.

That error huge so I am placing some part here.

> Update Failed:      LiveSite Pack ‹ PropelApps — WordPress addLoadEvent = function(func){if(typeof jQuery!="undefined")jQuery(document).ready(func);else if(typeof wpOnload!='function'){wpOnload=func;}else{var oldonload=wpOnload;wpOnload=function(){oldonload();func();}}}; var ajaxurl = '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', pagenow = 'toplevel_page_live-site', typenow = '', adminpage = 'toplevel_page_live-site', thousandsSeparator = ',', decimalPoint = '.', isRtl = 0; img.wp-smiley, img.emoji { display: inline !important; border: none !important; box-shadow: none !important; height: 1em !important; width: 1em !important; margin: 0 .07em !important; vertical-align: -0.1em !important; background: none !important; padding: 0 !important; }   window._wpemojiSettings = {"baseUrl":"https://s.w.org/images/core/emoji/2.2.1/72x72/","ext":".png","svgUrl":"https://s.w.org/images/core/emoji/2.2.1/svg/","svgExt":".svg","source":{"concatemoji":"http://www.propelapps.com.au/wp-includes/js/wp-emoji-release.min.js?ver=4.7-alpha-38779"}}; !function(a,b,c){function d(a){var c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j=b.createElement("canvas"),k=j.getContext&&j.getContext("2d"),l=String.fromCharCode;if(!k||!k.fillText)return!1;switch(k.textBaseline="top",k.font="600 32px Arial",a){case"flag":return k.fillText(l(55356,56806,55356,56826),0,0),j.toDataURL().length<3e3?!1:(k.clearRect(0,0,j.width,j.height),k.fillText(l(55356,57331,65039,8205,55356,57096),0,0),c=j.toDataURL(),k.clearRect(0,0,j.width,j.height),k.fillText(l(55356,57331,55356,57096),0,0),d=j.toDataURL(),c!==d);case"diversity":return k.fillText(l(55356,57221),0,0),e=k.getImageData(16,16,1,1).data,f=e[0]+","+e[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuIWE.png)+","+e[2]+","+e[3],k.fillText(l(55356,57221,55356,57343),0,0),e=k.getImageData(16,16,1,1).data,g=e[0]+","+e[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuIWE.png)+","+e[2]+","+e[3],f!==g;case"simple":return k.fillText(l(55357,56835),0,0),0!==k.getImageData(16,16,1,1).data[0];case"unicode8":return k.fillText(l(55356,57135),0,0),0!==k.getImageData(16,16,1,1).data[0];case"unicode9":return k.fillText(l(55358,56631),0,0),0!==k.getImageData(16,16,1,1).data[0];case"emoji4":return k.fillText(l(55357,56425,55356,57341,8205,55357,56507),0,0),h=j.toDataURL(),k.clearRect(0,0,j.width,j.height),k.fillText(l(55357,56425,55356,57341,55357,56507),0,0),i=j.toDataURL(),h!==i}return!1}

[image]